Prisma query with mode 'insensitive' does not work
import { prisma } from '@/prisma/prisma-client';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const query: string = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('query') || '';

  try {
    console.log(`Search query: '${query}'`);

    // Запрос с Prisma
    const products = await prisma.product.findMany({
      where: {
        name: {
          contains: query,
          mode: 'insensitive',
        },
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(products);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error executing query:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'An error occurred' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

In the database is a pizza with the name 'Cheez'. If I try
http://localhost:3000/api/product/search?query=cheez
nothing is returned, just [].
Updating prisma@client did not help.

And what is your problem?

Эта проблема Vercel, либо разверни базу данных локально или продолжай работать с Vercel, но так некоторые запросы с query параметрами будут некорректно возвращать данные, для учебы некритично

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
